# Applying a Variable to a DIV CLASS In PHP

Tags: php, css

I am attempting to make the TOP and LEFT parameters of this DIV class variable. Here are snippets of my code

First in the style.php file:-

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/css");
$top='100';
$left='200';
?>
.testbox {
     float:left;
     position:absolute;
     top:<?php echo $top; ?>px;
     left:<?php echo $left; ?>px;
     background-size:2000px 2000px;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
     width:50px;
     height:100px;
     border:1px solid #b3bdc2;
     z-index:1;

     }
```

In my main script (gettrains.php)

```
        $top='100';
        $left='500';
        echo "<div style='top:$top;left:$left' class='testbox'>
        <p>$answer</p>
        </div>";
```

I have also put the below line into my gettrains.php script

```
<link href="style.php" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I basically have two problems:

1) The box is positioned at 100,200 as per style.php and NOT 100,500 .........my new variables

2) Since including the "link href="style.php.............etc at the top of the gettrains.php file it keeps reloading when previously it did not (Its part of an AJAX call (GET) that worked fine before including the LINK to style.php

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: two things: 1) CSS numbers that aren't `0` are illegal. You need a unit following any number for it to mean anything, like 'em', or 'px' etc. In this case, you need to add "px" to your numbers for them to work. 2) generating the style.php file is good, generating those values into the HTML source as `style="..."` attributes is not, so stick with the `<link>` approach =D

Comment: Hi Mike the only edit I've made was to change a couple " to a ' which I had incorrectly put in. I still have the same problem and have made no other changes.

Comment: hm, could have sworn you added 'px' to you CSS, but maybe I misread! I'll delete my comment since it was unfair if you didn't edit it.

Comment: Okay thanks. px was always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd thing to do, as PHP can only generate the initial HTML source that the browser receives. You're basically saying "I need the box at 100/200 **and** 100/500". In a battle between CSS rules, the most specific rule wins. Normally that'd be `style="..."` but in this case you didn't add the `px` unit to the inline style so the browser rejects it as meaningless.

The "quick fix" here is to simply fix that problem: `echo "<div style='top:${top}px;left:${left}px' class='testbox'>` but the real problem here is that you're specifying two positions mutually exclusive positions at the same time without a clear indication of why you're doing the override. Which position does it need? PHP runs server-side so it can't really have any idea why 100/500 is better than 100/200 (what are those numbers based on? Unlike on-page JavaScript, PHP can't check what is good positioning, so these are just magic numbers).

As simple positioning information for a specific element, it's much better to generate those positions as their own, named, CSS class such as:

```
.initial {
  top:  <?php echo $top_override; ?>px;
  left: <?php echo $left_override; ?>px;
}
```

and then in the HTML that you generate, use `<div class="initial">...` so that the master CSS applies, but the `.initial` class wins, setting the correct left value (since the top values are the same). Then, once the page is rendered by the browser, you'll have to use JavaScript to do any further dynamic positional changes.

Comment: Hi Mike . Its the 100 500 I'm after. It will actually change but put it in as a starter for 10. The 100,200 in style.php was just a default I thought I had to put in........no other reason

Comment: the same idea still holds though: don't inline that style. If you have some idea of why you're setting it to that, create a class with those values, have it live in your stylesheet, and give your element that class (in addition to any other classes you need)

Comment: Just giving the quick fix a go

Comment: It works. The quick fix has allowed me to remove the style.php folder link that was causing me problems - (I have set the box style in my gettrains.php file.). The box correctly positions and the reloading has stopped. Thank you.

Comment: Re your comments with the .initial. How do I run both the class="Initial" and class="testbox" in the same statement.....

Comment: class="class1 class2 class2 etc"